# Configuration of multiple tenants on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, multi-tenant, azure-service-fabric

We have a SaaS application containing several .Net services that we would like to host on Azure Service Fabric (SF). We'd have one application instance for each tenant, so each tenant would have his own set of services running.

The question is: how do we best configure each instance, as each tenant has specific application settings (like a different connection string to databases in an elastic pool)?

I figured using the `Parameter` files in the SF Application Type :

- have a PublishProfile XML file for each tenant (in Visual Studio)
- point each PublishProfile XML file to its own Parameter XML file under the ApplicationParameters folder
- in the `ApplicationManifest.xml` define a parameter for each application setting I  want to be able to change per tenant
- in the `Config\Settings.xml` file (config package of a service) have a parameter for each application setting
- in the `ApplicationManifest.xml` use a `ConfigOverride` in the `ServiceManifestImport` to override a parameter in the `Config\Settings.xml` with the parameter value from the Parameters XML file

Of course, in production we would pass the parameter values via powershell instead of publishing via Visual Studio, but the point is : is this the way configuration should be done when you have multiple application instances, i.e. using the Parameter settings? Or is there another way?